# Determining the value of registers in CPU

Tags: cpu-architecture, riscv

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xILC.png)
During a particular clock cycle, consider the CPU shown in the drawing.
Assume that the following initial data is present (all values are shown in decimal):
x3=72, x4=40, x8=0, x16=24, x17=56, x18=48, x20=40, x24=80
Assume that the following five instructions are in the pipeline 
(the first column is the instruction's address; all values are shown in decimal):
66992 beq x17,x16,24
66996 addi x17,x8,8
67000 sd x20,40(x24)
67004 sub x10,x4,x18
67008 ori x27,x3,16
During the cycle in question, the instruction on the first line of the above list was in the 
write-back stage and the instruction on the last line of the above list was in the instruction fetch
 stage.
How Do I determine the value of L1 , L2 and L3 ?:

---

I am not sure how to begin addressing this type of questions. Like L1 isabout
 reading data 1. But where will it read data from. It seems 
L1 is connected to Instruction[31-0], Instruction[30,14-12] and 
Instruction[11-7]. So it will read data from one of this instructions
If I think over the fact that `or x21,x3,x19` was in the instruction fetch stage
 then L1 should contain the value of x3 = 72 
Not sure if that is correct

Comment: Is there any online resource where I could practice this type of questions. Which has explained answers

Comment: https://riscv.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Wed1600-RISC-V-Cache-Vmin-Reduction-Zimmer-UC-Berkeley.pdf

This breaks down the L1 and L2 cache operation very in depth.

Comment: I think L1 and L2 don't refer to cache here. It's just a symbol for data piplines if you see in the image attached. The names probably are confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The lines: Read register 1, Read register 2, Write register are all 5-bit lines that are register names (numbers) coming from fields of the instruction.  Write data is a 64-bit lined that comes from an earlier instruction (later in the diagram).

You have to know some of the basics of decoding in the processor and what each instruction does to know this.

Unfortunately, your diagram is seriously abstract — in particular, the line L2, for example, is not labeled.

Have a look at this article explaining some things about timing: https://www.codementor.io/@erikeidt/logic-block-diagrams-w6zxr6sp6.  Of particular note, the instruction fields that feed Read register 1, and 2 and Write register are labeled with instruction field bit positions that you can relate to the RISC V instruction formats in an presentation such as this: [https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61c/resources/su18_lec/Lecture7.pdf](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ecs61c/resources/su18_lec/Lecture7.pdf) (see slide 8 for an overview of the formats).

These two pieces of information, put together, tell us that Read register 2, for example, comes from instruction field 24:20, which corresponds to what is known as the `rs2` field of R-Type, S-Type and SB-type instructions.

It is a bit of a leap, but the corresponding value on L1 is the 64-bit (assuming  RV64) value looked up in the Registers (register file) found in the register named by L2 (at the time that lookup is executed).

So, if you know a little bit about how the I-Type instruction, for example, works differently from an R-Type instruction, that will inform you as to what is on some of these datapaths.

L3 is the ALU comparator output, which on some processor designs is output on the EX stage to indicate whether two registers compare for equality or not, and used by conditional branch instructions (beq and bne).

These diagrams are all woefully abstract from what actually has to happen in the hardware, as RISC V has many more conditional branches than == and !=, but many of these diagrams are adapted from the original MIPS, which only had those two comparators for conditional branching.

L4 is a new PC value, used when a conditional branch is taken.

L5, hard to see in this diagram, but is the ALU output forwarded to some MUXes that choose what value for Write data.

(Your diagram also includes pipeline registers & stages, many other's don't and certain details are easier to understand on the corresponding single cycle diagram.)

---

Yes, for that `ori` with register `x3`, L2 would be 3 (for x3) and L1 would be 72.